# How to prevent validation method firing on every keystroke after the initial validation failure?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with the "*name*" input field, and it should be unique for the whole application. The check happens via Ajax call when a user tries to save the form. If user leaves the "*name*" empty and then saves the form, it will be followed by a validation error. After this point, every keystroke for the "*name*" field will be resulted in Ajax call. How to prevent this?

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="${Name}" />
```

**JS**:

```
var validationParams = {
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      uniqueName: true
    }
  }
};

...

$.validator.addMethod("uniqueName", uniqueNameFn, 'error msg');

...

saveBtn.on('click', save);

...

function save() {
  templateRegion.find(form).validate(validationParams);
  if (!templateRegion.find(form).valid()) return;

  $.ajax({ ... });
}

// FIRES ON EVERY KEYSTROKE IF 'required' VALIDATION INITIALLY FAILS
function uniqueNameFn(value, elemChanged) {
  $.ajax({ ... });
}
```

Comment: You could fire a `setTimeout` function that checks the user has stopped typing after a certian amount of time from when they initially started typing - after then it can check.

Comment: You can set some value say 'isValid' to false and the next time that fires if !isvalid u can use    event.preventDefault() or just return

Comment: Just a tip... I'd move the `.validate()` line outside of your `save` function.  `.validate()` is meant to initialize the `form`, and that only needs to happen _once_ upon DOM ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day it wasn't jQuery or JavaScript problem. It was a nested forms situation.

Answer (score 1):

set onkeyup to false in your validationParams object

```
var validationParams = {
    onkeyup:false,
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            uniqueName: true
        }
    }
};
```